# Need suggestion to create an interactive GUI using Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to create one demo app in java.I want to create an interactive GUI for that.I know about swing. But can anyone please guide/suggest me is there any other way to create a GUI except swing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) is a popular alternative to Swing.  The Eclipse IDE is written with SWT.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse RCP or SWT are good alternatives, otherwise you can go with the "new" [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html) framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, you can use [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). It does have an [eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php). WindowsBuilder gives you drag-drop functionality to build your application quickly.

Here is a snap-shot of WindowsBuilder

[image: WindowsBuilder in eclipse]

Comment: Thanks Apurv.. But above form is the same as we seen  since last so many years..I've not tried WindowBuilder yet..Let me check it..